# Tech consideration for ios application

Tags: ios, ios-appstore

I am thinking about publishing an application for a client,
We are considering two approaches

1. An application which basically is a wrapper for a responsive website
2. A native application

I came across this article:
https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#minimum-functionality

stating that apple will reject my application.

If i try to upload my application will it be rejected?

Comment: Basically only Apple can answer that, especially given the fact the the interpretation of the App Store Guidelines shifts over time.

Answer (score 1):

The app will not be rejected if it provides functionality outside the scope of the standard website.

Apple only rejects apps which are specifically just wrappers on a site.

Example, I wrote an app that was basically a wrapper on a site, they rejected it, I added the ability in a second tab to draw and post the pic to the site (a novel feature), they approved it.